# Golang flag library: Unable to override Usage function that prints out command line usage

Tags: go, flags, command-line-tool

I am working on a simple command line tool and I found the default Usage message a bit lacking. I want to define my own and I think I am doing it right I am referring to [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/uaycqgIurf).

I commented out most of the code I had written so the file containing the main function now looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // set the custom Usage function
    setupFlags(flag.CommandLine)
    // define flags...
    // then parse flags
    flag.Parse()
    // custom code that uses flag values...
}

func setupFlags(f *flag.FlagSet) {
    f.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Println("foo bar")
    }
}
```

It seems like this should work, but it doesn't. When running `<binary> -h` I get the default usage message and not my custom `foo bar` message that I defined in my custom function. I am using Go version 1.3.3 on OSX. I found [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b2487ef6a399790cfe57127c3f50fc59341460e4) but it is for Go 1.4rc2.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

Actually revisiting your code it works! What version of Go are you using? Maybe you need to rebuild your code.

The decision of what `Usage` function to call is in the `flag.go` source file, [line 708](http://golang.org/src/flag/flag.go?#L708), unexported function `usage()` (this is from Go 1.4):

```
func (f *FlagSet) usage() {
    if f.Usage == nil {
        if f == CommandLine {
            Usage()
        } else {
            defaultUsage(f)
        }
    } else {
        f.Usage()
    }
}
```

This tells if the `FlagSet.Usage` is not `nil`, it will be called. If it is not called for you, it's most likely you're using a Go version prior to 1.4 (which you confirmed in your comment).

But since you're using the default `flag.CommandLine` flagset, you can simply write:

```
// Note "flag.Usage" instead of "f.Usage"

flag.Usage = func() {
    fmt.Println("foo bar")
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have been reading the commits to flag.go. They are for 1.4rc2 and I am still on 1.3.3. The code I posted does not work for me. But your solution of setting `flag.Usage` did work.